# Casting when querying ElasticSearch data

Tags: elasticsearch, casting, nest

Is there a way in elasticsearch where I can cast a string to a long value at query time?

I have something like this in my document:
"attributes": [
         {
            "key": "age",
            "value": "23"
         },
         {
            "key": "name",
            "value": "John"
         },
      ],

I would like to write a query to get all the persons that have an age > 23. For that I need to cast the value to an int such that I can compare it when the key is age.

The above document is an example very specific to this problem.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also share your mapping, especially the mapping of the `attributes` field? Also do you have any other attribute in that array whose content might also be numeric (e.g. `height`, `weight`, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scripting for that

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "filter": {
         "script": {
           "script": "foreach(attr :  _source['attributes']) {if ( attr['key']=='age') { return attr['value'] > ageValue;} } return false;",
           "params" : {
                "ageValue"  : 23
            }

         }
       },
       "query": {
         "match_all": {}
       }
     }
  }
}
```

**UPD:** Note that dynamic scripting should be enabled in elasticsearch.yml.

Also, I suppose you can archive better query performance by refactoring you document structure and applying appropriate mapping for age field.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem! I'm not refactoring it to become numeric because I want the documents to be generic - that's why I chose the key-value pair approach.

Comment: @Adina, Elasticsearch documents are key-value by nature. You can store different set of attributes in documents of the same type.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I understand that, however, I'm publishing the data through an odata api endpoint and so I want my documents to be typed. Also, I want my attributes to be able to store anything inside (properties that I didn't even think of before - age, eye color, hair color, etc.) and so because of that I chose this option.